# Cannot start the emulator for Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: visual-studio-2013, windows-phone-8.1, windows-8.1, emulation

this is the error I get when I try to launch the emulator:

[image]

I have windows 8.1 professional, and the emulator as its shown is compatible with w8.1, and I installed the suitable VS update.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the message suggests, you probably don't have Hyper-V enabled. If your PC supports it (which it should if the CPU isn't very old), you'll probably have to enable it from your BIOS (look up your motherboard or laptop model number for the exact location of the option in the BIOS).

On the off chance that it's enabled there but disabled from Windows, type "Turn Windows features on or off" from your Windows search charm and see if the Hyper-V option is checked or not. If the option isn't there at all then it's probably disabled from the BIOS or not supported by your CPU.

Answer (score 2):

Also make sure you are running the 64 bit version of Windows 8.1 Pro. From the error shown it sounds like you may have the 32 bit OS installed.